# c# Modify a Cell in Mysql using a ComboBox in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, combobox

I'm new developing and I need a detailed answered, I'm sorry for my bad english...
I will try to explain myself the best I can..
I've 2 tables in Mysql

```
 table1:  id_ticket , ticket_description, ticket_status(id_status)         
 table2 :    id_statu , status_name
```

In my application I use all the information inside table1 to fill a DataGridView, also I've added a comboBox column, the combobox displays "status_name" from table2, I want to modify ticket_status with the information contained in the comboBox, how can I do that?

this is my code:

```
public void CreateAssignedToMe(string ConnString)
    {
        string assignedTo = textBoxUid.Text;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ticket_assignee='"+assignedTo+"' AND ticket_resolution < 3;";

        AssignToMe = new AssignedToMe();
        AssignToMe.ConnString = ConnString;
        DataGridView dgvReports = AssignToMe.dataGridViewAssignedToMe;

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter daUsers = new MySqlDataAdapter(query,ConnString);
            DataSet dsUsers = new DataSet();
            daUsers.Fill(dsUsers,"report");
            dgvReports.DataSource = dsUsers;
            dgvReports.DataMember = "report";
            dgvReports.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgvReports.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgvReports.Columns["ticket_departmentResponsive"].Visible = false;
            dgvReports.Columns["ticket_assignee"].Visible = false;


                string queryStatus = "SELECT * FROM status";
                MySqlDataAdapter daStatus = new MySqlDataAdapter(queryStatus, ConnString);                  
                DataSet dsStatus = new DataSet();
                MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daStatus);
                daStatus.Fill(dsStatus, "Resolution");

                daStatus.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                BindingSource StatusBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                StatusBindingSource.DataSource = dsStatus;
                StatusBindingSource.DataMember = "Resolution";
                cbbox.HeaderText = "Resolution";
                cbbox.DropDownWidth = 90;
                cbbox.DataSource = StatusBindingSource;
                cbbox.DisplayMember = "status_name";
                dgvReports.Columns.Add(cbbox);



            AssignToMe.ShowDialog();

        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

}

I'm not able to post Images :(

Comment: I think that I've to use something like a EventHandler, but I'm not sure how to do that, or maybe using a button to update the information, but how I can get the specified row for the combobox that was modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx). Function assigned to that event will be executed when you change any cell value.

```
// adding event handler (somewhere after dgvReports initialization)
dgvReports.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvReports_CellValueChanged);

// function that handles event
private void dgvReports_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // `e` argument will contain e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex properties
    // they may be used to determine which particular cell was changed

}
```

In event handler you should check what column/cell was changed (row and cell index should be passed thru `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e` argument to your method that handles `CellValueChanged` event).

After that check - you should "do your update".

Comment: Thanks for the answer,now I'm able to do what I wanted, just one question, every time I modify a cell, I have to click on other cell to run dgv_Reports_CellValueChanged, there's a way to run it immediately, without clicking on other cell?

Comment: Im not sure, but probably you have to confirm cell edit by pressing enter (or leaving that cell). It works as it works because Value property of cell is changed after you "confirm value edit" (by enter key) or when you leave cell. Maybe its possible to call that event just after picking value, but i don't know how to do it. Maybe this is good subject for another question.

Comment: I suggest to ask another question, maybe something like this: "How to update DataGridViewComboBoxCell value without leaving cell or pressing enter?"